# How to counter this invalid method declaration error?

Tags: java

```
class ThreeDObject
{
 wholeSurfaceArea();
 volume();
}
class Cube extends ThreeDObject
{
public void input()
{
 double a,c_area,c_volume;
 Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter one side of the cube: ");
 a = sc1.nextDouble();
 }
 public void wholeSurfaceArea()
 {
   c_area = 6*a*a;
 }
public void volume()
{
 c_volume = a*a*a;
}
public void display()
{
 wholeSurfaceArea();
 volume();
 System.out.println("The surface area of the Cube is: "+c_area);
 System.out.println("The volume of the Cube is: "+c_volume);
}
}


public class FindVolumeArea
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  { 
     Cube cb = new Cube();
     cb.input();
     cb.display();

   } 
}
```

This gives me this error:

```
FindVolumeArea.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
   wholeSurfaceArea();
   ^
FindVolumeArea.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
   volume();
   ^
```

I tried adding `Void` but it didn't work.

Comment: `public double wholeSurfaceArea(); public double volume();`

Comment: You probably want those methods to be `abstract` as well.

Comment: If the methods are going to be `abstract`, then so does the class.

Comment: It's working without the double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class ThreeDObject {
    abstract public void wholeSurfaceArea();

    abstract public void volume();
}

class Cube extends ThreeDObject {
    double a, c_area, c_volume;

    public void input() {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter one side of the cube: ");
        a = sc1.nextDouble();
    }

    public void wholeSurfaceArea() {
        c_area = 6 * a * a;
    }

    public void volume() {
        c_volume = a * a * a;
    }

    public void display() {
        wholeSurfaceArea();
        volume();
        System.out.println("The surface area of the Cube is: " + c_area);
        System.out.println("The volume of the Cube is: " + c_volume);
    }
}


public class FindVolumeArea {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Cube cb = new Cube();
        cb.input();
        cb.display();

    }
}
```

Explaination:

1. If you are not giving definition of a method then mark it as `abstract`
2. Variable declaration inside a method is local to the specific method.
3. Instance variable/ Class variable can be access across the method of the class.

Read more about variables and class [here](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-class-methods-instance-variables.php)